# Django update and save asynchronous?

Tags: django, django-models

We have a model that only allows one instance of it to be `active` :

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   active = models.BooleanField()

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.active:
           MyModel.objects.update(active=False)
       super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This appears to work, passes simple tests to ensure only one instance is ever active.

However, it was recently used on our production server and appears to be behaving as if the `update` call is executing *after* the save and so all instances are ending up with `active=False` - this doesn't happen all the time.

Could it be that the update is running after the save somehow? Or do I need to look elsewhere for the issue?

Comment: Your current code is not safe from race conditions. If two `MyModel` objects are saved at the same time, then it's quite easy for `update()` called in the first object's save to happen after the second object is saved. You could exclude the current object from your `update()` call, which would help but I don't think solves the problem entirely.

Answer (score 2):

> Django update and save asynchronous?

No, Django's `update` and `save` are not asynchronous.

> Could it be that the update is running after the save somehow?

Yes, it is possible.

What I suspect is happening is that when Django tells your database to perform updates, your database immediately tells Django that the updates have taken place while it performs the updates **in the background**.

And so, your Django code proceeds on to the next statement since it has gotten a response from the database.

> Or do I need to look elsewhere for the issue?

Yes. Maybe ask this question under your database's SO tag, or mailing list. A simple fix I can think of is by explicitly locking your table while the updates are taking place. Although I'm not sure about what's the best approach as I don't have much experience working with databases.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Have asked a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51130855/would-a-django-orm-update-command-return-before-the-update-actually-happens-in-p

The update call returning before it actually completes on the DB end is what I meant by asynchronous, I should have explained that better.