# Would a Django ORM update command return before the update actually happens in Postgres?

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a couple of lines of code that have an `QuerySet.update` call followed by an `Instance.save` call. Both on the same model, where the save call overwrites the initial update (e.g. Update a column in all records to X, then save the same column in my specific instance to Y).

When performing the update command, could/would Postgres return a positive result *before* the update is completed? Somehow my the end result *sometimes* is behaving as if the `update` call happens *after* the save. By *sometimes*, I mean on our production servers where the DB is on a different physical machine to the application code. I can not reproduce this behavior locally on a Docker setup on my laptop (one container for Django, one for Postgres).